# Meteor: Error updating a Document's array with <input> fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am running into the following problem with MeteorJS and onInput events acting on a MongoDB document.

In the DB I have a Collection whose elements each contain an array. The array contains objects which have properties including `id` and `inputValue`. I want to display each object's `inputValue` in an HTML `input` field. I would also like that when the user deletes all the content of an input field, the corresponding object in the array gets deleted (through an onInput event) and that the array's contents get redisplayed.

This should be straightforward in Meteor and below is the code I'm using. However I'm running into the following problem:

When two or more objects in the array initially have an identical `inputValue` (such as in the code below: the two "aaa" strings), the array does not get reactively redisplayed properly. I'd expect to be left with one input field containing "aaa", but the field is empty.

This does not happen when it is the last of the identical inputs' value that gets deleted (the second "aaa" in this case), nor when the values are different (changing in the code one of the "aaa"s to "aba" for example makes it work as expected). Note that the text outside the input field gets updated correctly and so is the DB itself.

**main.html**:

```
<body>
    {{#with getData}}
    <form>
        {{#each array1}}
            <input id="{{id}}" type="text" value="{{inputValue}}"> 
            (id:{{id}}, inputValue: {{inputValue}})<br>
        {{/each}}
    </form>
    {{/with}}
</body>
```

**main.js**:

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('myCollection');

Meteor.methods({
    delete: function (colId, subItemId) {
        MyCollection.update({id: colId}, {$pull: {array1: {id: subItemId}}});
    }
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // make sure collection is empty then insert 1 document
    if (MyCollection.find().count() !== 0) {
        MyCollection.remove({id: 101});
    }
    MyCollection.insert({
        id: 101,
        array1: [
            { id: 1, inputValue: "aaa" },
            { id: 2, inputValue: "aaa" }
        ]
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.helpers({
        getData: function () {
            if (MyCollection.findOne({})) { // wait until collection is available
                return MyCollection.findOne({id: 101});
            }
        }
    });
    Template.body.events({
        "input input": function (event) {
            if ($(event.target).val() == "") {
                Meteor.call("delete", 101, Number($(event.target).attr("id")));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? I'm new to Meteor so I'm posting this as a question here first. I'm using Meteor 1.1.0.3, a new default project and tried this on recent versions of Safari and Firefox.